# Filling a std::tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, boost-fusion

I have a overloaded function which looks like:

```
template<typename T>
T getColumn(size_t i);

template<>
std::string getColumn<std::string>(size_t i) {
    if(i == 0)
        return "first";
    else
        return "other";
}

template<>
int getColumn<int>(size_t i) {
    return i*10;
}

// ...
```

Now I want to implement the function

```
template<typename... Values>
std::tuple<Values...> getColumns();
```

Which creates a tuple (for the return value) and calls `getColumn` for every element of the tuple (saving the return value in that element), where `i` is the position of the element. The code which generates the return value of `getColumn` is simplified (in reality it gets the value from a database).

But I have no idea how to do that.

My best try was with boost::fusion::for_each but I wasn't able to hand `i` down to `getColumn`.

Another try was with the iterators from boost::fusion, but that also didn't work:

```
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
tuple<Values...> t;
auto it = fusion::begin(t);
while(it != fusion::end(t)) {
    getColumn(distance(fusion::begin(t), it), fusion::deref(it));
    it = fusion::next(it); // error: assignment not allowed
}
```

How can I call `getColumn` for every Type from `Values...` with the correct value for `i` and save the results in a `std::tuple`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map each element of a parameter pack to its index within the pack - this is the typical use case for the "index sequence trick":

```
template <int... I> struct index_sequence {};
template <int N, int... I>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N-1,N-1,I...> {};
template <int... I>
struct make_index_sequence<0, I...> : index_sequence<I...> {};

template<typename... Values, int... I>
auto getColumns(index_sequence<I...>) ->
  decltype(std::make_tuple(getColumn<Values>(I)...)) {
    return std::make_tuple(getColumn<Values>(I)...);
}

template<typename... Values>
auto getColumns() ->
  decltype(getColumns<Values...>(make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Values)>())) {
    return getColumns<Values...>(make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Values)>());
}
```

[Live demo at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1354af923ca0eef1)

Comment: A nice side effect is that the helper function is also useful.  But can it be eliminated via default args, (or in other words) making the helper function the only one?

Comment: @Yakk I think not: the intermediate type is necessary from which to deduce the indices. There is no syntax specified for providing a default to a parameter pack (See [temp.param]/1).

Comment: Can `Values...` be deduced, used to produce the default argument for the second argument, from which `Is...` is then deduced?  Probably not: even if it compiled, I woukd want to standard delve to make sure it was not an accidental extension.

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks! The helper function isn't a problem for me. I've integrated the functions in a class and just made the helper private. Just be careful with decltype on member functions as GCC has a bug so you'll need to explicitly use `this->` (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57543). Clang doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `auto`:

```
template<typename... Values>
auto getColumns() -> decltype(std::make_tuple(getColumns<Values>()...))
{
    return std::make_tuple(getColumns<Values>()...);
}
```

In C++14, you'll be able to omit the `-> decltype...` part, since it will be deduced from the function body.

Comment: Needs indexes: OP wants to call `GetColumn<T>(i)...`