# getting template type from lambda auto

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I'm in a bit of a pickle, following up my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168220/template-variadic-function-arbitrary-number-of-classes-with-arbitrary-number-of) and using a code similar to the one I [posted here](https://ideone.com/Fq242E).

1. I use a variadic template function which accepts variadic objects
2. It packs them into a tuple
3. Iterates them using the `visitor` idiom
4. Binds for each object a callback

Instead of the original minified example shown below:

```
template <typename... Args>
void make_classes(Args... args)
{
    auto t = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
    unsigned int size = std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value;
    auto execute = [](auto & obj){ obj.operator()(); };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        visit_at(t, i, execute);
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how I can deduce the template type of the `auto` lambda, so that I can bind it:

```
template <typename... Args>
void make_classes(Args... args)
{
    auto t = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
    unsigned int size = std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value;
    auto execute = [](auto & obj){ 
        // obtain type of obj as T?
        auto callback = std::bind(&T::deserialise, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
        // do something else here using this callback.
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        visit_at(t, i, execute);
    }
}
```

There's a catch: the parameter objects are non-copyable (although I could change that), but I would like to know if/how the above could work by deducing the template type packed in the tuple as obtained by the visitor.

If I can't deduce the type inside the lambda, can I somehow *store* it within the tuple (e.g.,: type & object) in order to later extract it?

Comment: Don't you need `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know, how would that work?

Comment: @NathanOliver seems you're on to something,  using `decltype(obj` returns `error: type 'decltype(obj)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members` with the correct type printed in the error.

Comment: Oops.  typo.  If you want the type of `obj` then you just use `decltype(obj)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use another lambda:

```
auto callback = [&obj](auto& x){
    obj.deserialise(x);
};
```

`std::bind` is rarely useful. (If you really want to copy `obj`, you can drop the leading `&`.)

---

Moreover, you don't actually need a tuple...

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void for_each_arg(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{0,
        (void(f(std::forward<Args>(args))), 0)...
    };
}

template <typename... Args>
void make_classes(Args... args)
{
    for_each_arg([](auto& obj){
        auto callback = [&obj](auto& x) { obj.deserialise(x); };
        // do something with callback
    }, args...);
}
```

Comment: wow many thanks, this is a lot simpler, will take some time to digest.

Comment: @Ælex See [T.C.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30563282/2069064) for a good explanation.